# How Can I reset password using the user name instead email addres?

Tags: php, laravel, reset-password

I need to send the email to a specific user, the problem is that the system is designed so that many users can have the same email address, then the problem arises when I use the laravel password reset system, laravel finds the first user who has the email sent by the user
I first tried adding a column to the password reset tokens table that contains the username that you want to reset the password.

```
  public function sendRecoveryToken(Request $request)
  {
      $user = User::where('user', $request->username)->select(['email'])->first();
      $status = Password::sendResetLink(['email' => $user->email);
      DB::table('password_reset_tokens')->where('email', $user->email)->update(['user' => $user->userName]);
      return $status === Password::RESET_LINK_SENT
          ? back()->with(['state' => __($state)])
          : back()->withErrors(['email' => __($status)]);
  }
```

this sends a url with a token but with the first user for example I have 2 users with the same email

[image]
if xfeest wants to reset your password, the URL shows the user Jesse50

[image]
so how can I do it? :(

PS: Now it seems bad to me that many users have the same email but the customer wants to

Comment: Show the code of how user is fetched from DB in the moment password’s been reset.

Comment: @Tpojka is Laravel code and I can't access to it but it use the email in the password reset tokens to find the user

Comment: You will need more work about it since this approach can not use Eloquent's default purpose. If you check your [migration](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/10.x/database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_reset_tokens_table.php#L15C13-L15C48), you'll find that `password_reset_tokens.email` is primary field in the table so there is no way to have two users with same email by default. It's not just to PHP code, it's up to database design that should be changed.